# What "three days" is Richard Jewell referring to?

Tags: dialogue, richard-jewell

Richard Jewell comforts his crying mother after he yelled at her
for watching a war movie:

> Richard Jewell: You just sit down. You watch whatever you wanna watch.
> I don't care. And I'm sorry I yelled.

Richard Jewell says to his friends:

> Yeah, she's had about **three days** to be proud of her son...and then
> taken  away from her. Yep. That ain't right.

What "three days" is Richard Jewell referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Jewell#Olympic_bombing_accusation):

> Sometime after midnight, July 27, 1996, Eric Robert Rudolph [...] planted a green backpack containing a fragmentation-laden pipe bomb under a bench. Jewell was working as a security guard for the event. He discovered the bag and alerted Georgia Bureau of Investigation officers.
>
> [...]
>
> **Early news reports lauded Jewell as a hero** for helping to evacuate the area after he spotted the suspicious package. **Three days later, *The Atlanta Journal-Constitution* revealed that the FBI was treating him as a possible suspect**, based largely on a "lone bomber" criminal profile.